# Refer to the current directory in a shell script

Tags: shell

How do I refer to the current directory in a shell script?

So I have this script which calls another script in the same directory:

```
#! /bin/sh

#Call the other script
./foo.sh 

# do something ...
```

For this I got `./foo.sh: No such file or directory`

So I changed it to:

```
#! /bin/sh

#Call the other script
foo.sh 

# do something ...
```

But this would call the `foo` script which is, by default, in the PATH. This is not what I want.

So the question is, what's the syntax to refer `./` in a shell script?

Comment: `./` means the _current working directory_, not _the directory that stores the currently executing script file_. I'm not sure of any mechanism to get the directory containing the currently executing script. But if your first script is in the `PATH`, then so is the second script...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If both the scripts are in the same directory and you got the `./foo.sh: No such file or directory` error then the most likely cause is that you ran the first script from a different directory than the one where they are located in. Put the following in your first script so that the call to `foo.sh` works irrespective of where you call the first script from:

```
my_dir=`dirname $0`
#Call the other script
$my_dir/foo.sh
```

Comment: How do you deal with spaces in the directory names? It throws an error

Comment: The full path to the directory is `$PWD/$my_dir`

Comment: https://github.com/marcellodesales/docker-puller/blob/master/dockerpuller/scripts/testing.sh#L8

Comment: Please note, that `$0` won't work as expected with _sourced_ scripts. For bash, there is the [`BASH_SOURCE`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) alternative to `$0`, which works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

The following code works well with spaces and doesn't require bash to work:

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPTDIR="$(dirname "$0")"

#Call the other script
"$SCRIPTDIR/foo.sh"
```

Also if you want to use the absolute path, you could do this:

```
SCRIPTDIR=`cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd`
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:
[Unix shell script find out which directory the script file resides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242538/unix-shell-script-find-out-which-directory-the-script-file-resides)

But as sarnold stated, "./" is for the *current **working** directory*.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it POSIX:

```
a="/$0"; a=${a%/*}; a=${a:-.}; a=${a#/}/; BASEDIR=$(cd $a; pwd)
```

Tested on many Bourne-compatible shells including the BSD ones.

As far as I know I am the author and I put it into public domain. For more info see:
https://blog.jasan.tk/posix/2017/05/11/posix_shell_dirname_replacement

Answer (score 1):

`script_dir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"  # rm the last / and the file name from BASH_SOURCE`

`$script_dir/foo.sh`

Reference: Alex Che's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution does not work if you have a space in the path to the directory containing the scripts.

If you can use bash, this worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
"${SCRIPTDIR}/foo.sh"
```