# Read variables from text file to shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script and a file text containing variables for this script in the same directory.
I need to read these variables but without this

```
. /path_to_my_file.file.txt
```

I don't want any paths inside my script.Doing this does not work

```
. file.txt
```

So what other possibilities i have?

Comment: No other possibility, _possibly_.

Comment: is it possible to define the path as a global variable using export ?

Comment: You can use an environment variable... export HERE=/users/fred/bloggs and then use ${HERE} in your script.

Answer (score 1):

See this question how to find out in which folder a script is: [Unix shell script find out which directory the script file resides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242538/unix-shell-script-find-out-which-directory-the-script-file-resides?rq=1)

Afterwards, you can use this path to source your "config" file.