# softlinking and awk scripts (path issue)

Tags: bash, awk, path, symlink

I have `main.sh` and `external.awk` files.

They are in the same directory.

From `main.sh` I am calling that external awk script like this:

```
awk -f external.awk ..
```

and of course it is working.

Now when I do:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /path/to/scripts/dir/main.sh main.sh
sudo ln -s /path/to/scripts/dir/external.awk external.awk
```

I can call my `main.sh` from whatever directory I am in.
But it gives me error on not being able to find `external.awk` script.

Why linking does not work in this case, shouldn't that

```
awk -f external.awk ..
```

call `external.awk` relative to folder where it is, thus in this case calling
that symbolic link which is in `/usr/local/bin` path?

**EDIT**

Soon after posting my question, I found this as a good way to handle this situation:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/AWKPATH-Variable.html

It is **not** POSIX compliant, but in this case it is not of an importance to me.

Comment: No, it will try to call the AWK script from *your* current directory, not the directory where the shell script is. See e.g. [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242538/unix-shell-script-find-out-which-directory-the-script-file-resides) to find a way to solve it.

Comment: Is there a way I can set `path` so that `external.awk` is found this way?

Comment: It works for the shell script because the shell uses `$PATH` to find programs to run.  It doesn't work for `awk` because the argument to `-f` is the pathname leading to the script file.  When you're in the same directory, `external.awk` is the name of the file in the current directory.  When you're somewhere else, then `-f external.awk` still specifies `./external.awk`, but the file doesn't exist.  If you have a script `pathfile`, which hunts a file on a path, you could use `awk -f $(pathfile external.awk) …` to locate the file for you.  If you don't have such a script, you could write one.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think this might be the better and much cleaner soulution to the problem. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/AWKPATH-Variable.html It applies to `gawk` obviously, but that is what I am working with.

Comment: +1 for the discovery and documentation of GNU `awk`'s AWKLIBPATH.  It does precisely what you want, and if you'll always be using GNU `awk`, it makes sense to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify main.sh to call awk as this:

```
awk -f /usr/local/bin/external.awk ..
```