# Shell script to discover the location of executing script for Windows and Unix?

Tags: windows, shell, unix, posix

I am calling a shell script from a remote location. How do I get the directory that contains the executing shell script (in Windows and Unix-based systems)?

I do not have access to bash on the host system. Git is installed (on the Windows machine) though so I can use its distribution of `sh.exe`.

I've followed the advice of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919044 and have the following:

### whatsmydirectory.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

a="/$0";
echo "$a"

a="${a%/*}";
echo "$a"

a="${a:-.}";
echo "$a"

a="${a##/}/";
echo "$a"

BINDIR=$(cd "$a"; pwd)
echo "$BINDIR"
```

This works fine on Unix-based systems. However, it doesn't work with Windows.

#### MacOS

This correctly returns the location of the script `/Users/username/Desktop`

```
username@mac Desktop % ./whatsmydirectory.sh 
/./whatsmydirectory.sh
/.
/.
./
/Users/username/Desktop
```

#### Windows

This returns the current working directory `/c`, rather than the location of the script `C:\Program Files\Some Program\`.

```
C:\>  C:/"Program Files"/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe "C:\Program Files\Some Program\whatsmydirectory.sh"
/C:\Program Files\Some Program\whatsmydirectory.sh

.
./
/c
```

How can I modify the shell script such that it works equally well on both Windows and Unix-like hosts?

Answer (score 0):

whatsmydirectory.sh

script_dir=$(dirname $0)

echo $script_dir